# Can't export object after modifications

Tags: export

So I opened a TurboSquid blender file in Blender and edited the object mesh but when I select it in object mode and export to fbx or obj it only exports the original unedited mesh.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend you to give some more Information like how you edited the Mesh. maybe even a Screenshot?

Comment: The Blender model is a group of Medieval Castle buildings.. I deleted all but one.. used delete edge and delete face on one small section, then selected a few vertices from the hole that created and closed the geometry. I then selected the model in Object mode and exported but it's not exporting the altered model, just the original. I've saved the Blender file but that didn't help. The deleted Castle sections are still getting exported also.

Comment: Figured it out. It was a layer issue. The geometry I modified worked but it was exporting the original also so it was appearing as though the modified version wasn't exported. After exporting from the proper layer it's all good.